# Constraint Layout not wrap content properly

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Anyone know why this isn't wrapping content properly? Something to do with the gradient and the way the label_view is constrained is causing it to match parent somehow?

thanks

https://pastebin.com/R85CBFPL

```
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/hero_gradient"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/gradient_guide"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_view"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/left_margin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="8dp"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/right_margin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="8dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="TEST TEXT"
            android:textColor="@color/pink"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gradient"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gradient"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_margin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/right_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"/>
```

Thats just a snippet of the offending parties.

Answer (score 0):

I must really be having a slow day. I was backwardly setting the centre.

I was doing

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gradient"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gradient"
```

But I should be doing

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/gradient"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/gradient"
```